# AngularJS $compile is not interpolating template

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use $compile to generate HTML from a template to pass to an external component.  Everything was working with $interpolate, but I then needed directives in the template and had to switch to $compile.  All other examples I've seen of $compile are used within a directive, so I don't think this is a duplicate question.

Here's some code that illustrates the problem.

View:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
   This is a test: <span ng-bind-html="valueList"></span>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $compile, $sce) {
   var linker = $compile('<ul><li ng-repeat="v in values">{{v}}</li></ul>');
   var scope = $scope.$new(true);
   scope.values = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
   var html = linker(scope).html();
   $scope.valueList = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/guvpb8om/

Comment: `ng-bind-html` doesn't compile directives ... simply injects the html only. Custom directive with template would work

Comment: I'm not expecting ng-bind-html to compile a directive; that's just a sample to illustrate the problem.  I'm trying to get an interpolated HTML string that will be passed to an external component, but I didn't want to muddy the waters with that complexity here.